# Using ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair as an async ReaderWriterLock equivalent

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

My application has several async methods that can access files on disk. As I learned the ordinary `ReaderWriterLockSlim` cannot be used in such case, I went looking for an equivalent. Found the `ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair` that looked very promising. I read a few enlightening blog posts about it and I started to think this could be the right choice for me.

So I changed all my reading tasks to use the Concurrent scheduler and writing tasks to use the Exclusive one. However, it turned out I was still getting `IOException`s saying the file is in use. Here's a simplified (and still failing) version of my code:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> Run()
{
    var schedulers = new ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair();
    var exclusiveFactory = new TaskFactory(schedulers.ExclusiveScheduler);
    var concurrentFactory = new TaskFactory(schedulers.ConcurrentScheduler);

    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    for (var i = 0; i < 40; ++i)
    {
        // Create some readers and (less) writers
        if (i % 4 == 0)
        {
            var writeTask = exclusiveFactory.StartNew(WriteToFile).Unwrap();
            tasks.Add(writeTask);
        }
        else
        {
            var readTask = concurrentFactory.StartNew(ReadFromFile).Unwrap();
            tasks.Add(readTask);
        }
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    return _contents;
}

private async Task ReadFromFile()
{
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream("file.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
    {
        await Task.Delay(500); // some other work
        _contents.Add(await reader.ReadToEndAsync());
    }
}

private async Task WriteToFile()
{
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream("file.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
    {
        await Task.Delay(500); // some other work
        await writer.WriteLineAsync("Lorem ipsum");
    }
}
```

Then I found [Stephen Cleary's blog post](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/async-and-scheduled-concurrency.html) with a warning in a red box:

> When an asynchronous method awaits, it returns back to its context. This means that ExclusiveScheduler is perfectly happy to run one task at a time, not one task until it completes. As soon as an asynchronous method awaits, it’s no longer the “owner” of the ExclusiveScheduler. Stephen Toub’s async-friendly primitives like AsyncLock use a different strategy, allowing an asynchronous method to hold the lock while it awaits.

"One task at a time, not one task until it completes" - now this is a bit confusing. Does this mean the `ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair` is not the right choice for this situation or am I using it incorrectly? Perhaps an `AsyncLock` should be used here instead (why isn't it a part of the framework)? Or would a plain old `Semaphore` be enough (I understand I wouldn't get the reader-writer division then, but maybe it's ok)?

Comment: _"Perhaps an AsyncLock should be used here instead"_ -- perhaps. Probably, even. _"why isn't it a part of the framework?"_ -- not really an answerable question, unless you talk to the framework authors. The usual answer is "cost exceeds benefit". Framework authors are always making tradeoffs between providing enough functionality and not providing too much. `Semaphore` or `SemaphoreSlim` would work fine, since they lack thread affinity. That said, since there are existing implementations for `AsyncReaderWriterLock`, why not use that?

Comment: I was thinking about using the AsyncEx library with its `AsyncReaderWriterLock` but unfortunately I need to target web, Xamarin and Windows Phone 8.1, so I'd have to use a pretty old version of it. Besides, I just wanted to give `ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair` a try as it looked promising.

Comment: Well, I think your assessment of `ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair` is correct: it would work for your scenario, but not if you also want to use `async`/`await`. You'd need to hold on to the thread for the duration. Noting, however, that it should not be hard to refactor your current async code, to push the reader/writer async down into a helper class that uses `ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair`. E.g. don't call `StreamReader.ReadToEndAsync()`, but rather a helper method that uses `concurrent.StartNew()` with a _non_-async call to `ReadToEnd()`.

Comment: That would use synchronous IO that AFAIK should be avoided. I'll go with plain old SemaphoreSlim.

Comment: If all the `Task` objects in your task graph are true "cold start" tasks—that is, backed by actual `Task`/`Task<TResult>` instances (as opposed to the lightweight hot-start variety the compiler emits for the async/await trampoline), then you can specify `TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent` to automatically delay a whole graph until the completion of its final child task. Hot tasks can be adapted to this by wrapping each with `Task.Run`—but the *child tasks only*; you still need a real `Task` as the graph root (parent) to keep the async trampoline from escaping prior to root completion.

Comment: @GlennSlayden: `AttachedToParent` should be used in some cases when doing dynamic task parallelism. It's not a good idea to use it for asynchronous tasks; although it would technically work, it sets up a dependency that is difficult to see in the code. `await` logically does the same thing but is explicit.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One way of thinking of `async` methods[1] is that they are split into tasks at each `await` point. To use your example:

```
private async Task WriteToFile()
{
  using (var fileStream = new FileStream("file.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
  using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
  {
    await Task.Delay(500); // some other work
    await writer.WriteLineAsync("Lorem ipsum");
  }
}
```

conceptually gets broken into three tasks:

1. A task that creates the `fileStream` and `writer`, and starts the `Task.Delay` (some other work).
2. A task that observes the result of `Task.Delay` and starts `WriteLineAsync`.
3. A task that observes the result of `WriteLineAsync` and disposes `writer` and `fileStream`.

`ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair` is a task scheduler, so its semantics only apply when there is a task running code. When `WriteToFile` is run with `ExclusiveScheduler`, it holds the exclusive scheduler lock while task (1) is running. Once the `Task.Delay` code has started, that task (1) is done, and it releases the exclusive scheduler lock. During the `500` millisecond delay, the exclusive scheduler lock is **not** held. Once that delay has completed, task (2) is ready and queued to the `ExclusiveScheduler`. It then takes the exclusive scheduler lock and does its (small) amount of work. When task (2) completes, it also releases the exclusive scheduler lock. Etc.

Task schedulers were designed to work with synchronous tasks. There is some support for them in `await` (i.e., `TaskScheduler.Current` is automatically captured and used to resume from an `await`), but in general they do not have expected semantics when working with asynchronous tasks. Each `await` is actually telling the task scheduler "this (sub)task is done".

> Does this mean the ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair is not the right choice for this situation?

Yes. `ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair` is not the right choice.

> Perhaps an AsyncLock should be used here instead (why isn't it a part of the framework)?

`SemaphoreSlim` supports asynchronous locking (with a more awkward syntax). But it may not on WP81 - I don't remember (`WaitAsync` was added later). To support a platform that old, you'd have to either use AsyncEx v4 or copy/paste [Stephen Toub's code](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/02/12/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-6-asynclock/).

> I understand I wouldn't get the reader-writer division then, but maybe it's ok?

It's not only OK, it's almost certainly preferable. Using a reader/writer lock when you really just need a lightweight lock is an extremely common mistake. In particular, just because some code has read semantics and other code has write semantics is *not* a good enough reason to use a RWL.

[1] For efficiency reasons, `async` methods are broken into chunks of code at `await` points, but those individual chunks of code aren't actually wrapped by `Task` objects unless a `TaskScheduler` is present.

Comment: Then when should I prefer a ReaderWriterLock over a simple lock?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'd give you another upvote for the reader/writer lock vs semaphore explanation if I could.

Comment: @barakcaf: When you have read/write semantics, reads considerably outnumber writes, and you have a high degree of lock contention. Only when *all three* elements are present is a RWL an appropriate solution.

Comment: @Stephen Cleary thank you very much - I really enjoy reading your blog and other stack oveflow answers - have learned so much from you.

Comment: You write: "In particular, just because some code has read semantics and other code has write semantics is not a good enough reason to use a [ReaderWriterLock]." Can you elaborate? In particular, how could any (ostensibly identified) semantic read/write collision be benign (maybe you didn't mean that, perhaps you were implying there's a wide range of other treatments, not mentioned), and what then *would* be a critical factor or tipping point in the choice to indeed use RWL?

Comment: @GlennSlayden: I don't mean that synchronization isn't necessary. I mean that a RWL isn't necessary. A plain old lock would do just as well. Jumping straight to RWL without a good reason is a common mistake.

Comment: @StephenCleary You say that ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair is not the right choice in this scenario. In which scenario _is_ it the right choice? This example seems like a very basic example of an async RWL. Would a requirement for this to work with CESP be that the methods have no awaits?

Comment: CESP is designed for TPL code, including TPL Dataflow. Yes, it won't behave as expected with `await`.